# How to Reset To Default Wifi Settings

Tags: wireless

I was trying to setup a TP - Link Wn821 but when a finish i restart and see that i dont have any access to wifi networks.Someone can give the command line to reset to default?

Comment: What are the steps that you took to set up your device? Did you install a driver? Which? Please edit your question to add helpful details. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello thank u for try to help me so i was following a tutorial from youtube that let me in this repository so i start to paste tha command lines and when i finish i lost wifi conections https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep 8192` and finally: `uname -r`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands in a terminal:

```
nmcli radio wifi off    
nmcli radio wifi on    
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```